# Reagrading URL mapping in node.js

Tags: node.js

How to map url from

```
http://localhost:3000
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

in node.js?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also this is an extremely broad question - can you provide more information on what you mean by "map", which users should get this redirect, what sort of code or technology you're using, etc. etc. etc.?  As is I think this question is fundamentally un-answerable.

Comment: Max is right, the question needs considerable improvement to become answerable. You can start from suggesting a user scenario (what do you want to get in the end) and describing what you have so far.

Comment: Basically when i host my website in amazon web services when i hit www.eagleeyetechnologies.com i should get my landing page.HTML5,CSS3 and node js are the technologies i have used.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/really-really-basic-routing-in-nodejs-with-express-d7cad5e3f5d5

basic routing guide using express

Comment: while the linked page may contain an answer to the question, please include the relevant bits into your answer so it is self-sufficient.  If the link ever breaks or disappears, the answer will be incomplete and thus of no use to the community.

Comment: Great suggestion @ochi
will update answer soon. Thanks